# Mounting mergerfs directory with bind mount under lxc shows nothing unless root or 555 permissions

Tags: permissions, lxc, bind, proxmox

So I'm using proxmox and have a few hard drives mounted to `/mnt/hdd1`, `/mnt/hdd2` etc

I use mergerfs so that they all show up as one drive. I then use a bind mount so that I can access the dir when in various lxc containers. I have the folder permissions set to 550 however, when I try `ls -la` on the directory, all it returns is "total 0". I can view the directory with `sudo ls -la` though so it does mount.

Changing the permissions to 555 lets me view the directory properly however I checked using id username and I am a member of the group the directory is owned by. Also, if I mount `/mnt/hdd1` for example using the same method, I can access the directory with permissions 550. I tried recreating the group.

Any ideas what is causing this?

I can access this fine from the host as the same user. (Again just a member of the group)

My mergerfs settings in `/etc/fstab` are `defaults,allow_other,use_ino,func.getattr=newest`. Using `default_permissions` instead of `allow_other` results in d?????????, but still works for root.